# Wiring Diagram Help - 6v 'Power-Wheels' Ride-On Upgrade

Tags: dc-motor, wiring, remote-control, diagram, reverse-polarity

**Hello,**

I have a 6v Ride On toy car that I want to upgrade to 12v without upgrading the entire electrical system as it is only design for 6v.
My issue? I'm not in the electrical trade and i'm trying to teach myself, and would like feedback on my wiring diagram. I'll try to provide as much detail as I can.

### **Working Description**

For anyone not familiar with the type of car in question; currently, the 6v battery powers a remote control compatible system. When powered on, I can select between remote control or manual use, and select between forward and reverse when in manual mode. At either the press of the foot pedal or input from the remote control, the cars onboard PCB magically calculates an output and will send either a positive or negative 6v to the rear motors to go forward or backward respectively.
(I can upload a front and back picture of this PCB if anyone is interested in tracing it)

### **Plan / 'Wants'**

- 12v battery
- DC-DC buck converter, stepping 12v down to 6 for the car's system
- Upgrade rear motors to be 12v compatible
- Have a single DPDT switch to change between 6v and 12v power at the rear wheels. The switch will either use the direct 6v signal from the PCB to power the motors, or interpret that signal to allow the motors to draw directly from the 12v battery.
- **No items in stock. To complete at the lowest possible cost**

### **Issue**

I can easily achieve most of the above, except interpreting the reverse polarity to drive rearward at 12v.
Initially, when switched to 12v mode, I simply had the 6v signal power a mosfet which was the electrical switch to either stop or drive forward.
I then realised I need to be able to reverse as well and a double throw type mosfet situation doesn't exist (?).

### **My Solution**

*Disclaimer - I am no electrical engineer. I have basic skills and understanding of electrical diagrams. I have tried my best to make it as easy to follow as possible but I know it could be better, and not all correct symbols are used.*
[image: Proposed Wiring Diagram]

### **Explanation**

FYI, I have not included any wiring that steps the voltage down for the PCB and anything to do with the PCB, even though that will exist in practise.

With the DPDT switch in the other position, 6v signal from the PCB is used to power the motors.
In the current positions depicted... the relays are wired to provide 'Normally Closed' positive polarity to the motors, controlled by a transistor (T1) that is powered by the 6v PCB signal.

If the PCB signal is reversed, NPN transistor (T2) should then activate, which in turn activates both relay coils. The reverse voltage will then flow directly through the relays and to the motor, being restricted by diodes. When the PCB signal stops, the relays cut power and further movement is ceased due to T1 not being activated.

### **Final Questions / TL:DR**

1. Will this solution actually work?
2. Does T1 have to be a MOSFET (capable of up to 10A current)?
3. Are there improvements I can make to this solution in general?
4. What are some other, (likely) more effecient solutions for a similar cost price?
5. Any better post tags to help target this post to the right people?

Thanks so much for your time.

### **----------Edit----------**

After seeing the initial comments and searching other forums, and learning that the relay contact voltage can be higher than the coil rated nominal voltage; I come across this solution... which other than using 2 batteries in series and lacking the ability to switch between 6v and 12v, is what I'm after. (Note, I already know it is a circuit breaker in the green circle... was added by another user)

[image]

I have translated this into a more accurate and fitting diagram for my application and would like to know if this is a viable and working solution.

[image]

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this - what is the benefit to you or the vehicle?

Comment: The ability to make it slow for the youngest child or faster for the oldest... without burning everything out by a simple 12v battery drop in.

Comment: You’re biting off more than you can chew.  I wouldn’t do this and I am an electrical engineer.  Even if you succeed, it will take a lot of time and will be much more likely to break or malfunction, possibly while your kids are in it.  From your circuit, it appears the 12V battery can apply 12V to the 6V battery which is bad.

Comment: Thanks for your input Joe. I may consider scrapping the idea. And just to be clear though, the 6v "battery" Is not a separate battery even though I've used that symbol. The 12v would be stepped down via a buck converter to supply 6v to the onboard PCB which then sends the signal back to the motors (represented by the 6v battery symbol). The only wiring that is then shared between the battery and the 6v section is earth and not the battery positive side (I question this too but according to YT is correct?). Is that the part you referred to as "applying 12v to the 6v 'battery'"?